# Mongo Db secondary setup

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

From last 1 week I am trying to setup replica set for my one node mongodb (3.4.2 version) but facing multiple issues. My primary node currently have around 650 gb of data and every day it is growing by 90 gb. First time I added new secondary node with empty data directory after almost a day it failed with too much of lag in oplog issue. Next time I tried manually copying data. After copy when restarted secondary it started giving me the error that I cannot synch from primary (There was not connection problem I was able to ping).  I again retried manual copy procedure but this time it failed with below error. As wired tiger issue is with specific collection file. I copied that file again and retried but it failed again with same issue. Can someone please help me in setting up secondary. Everyday it is becoming more difficult as data is growing and I cannot keep primary down for long time (During manual copy I stop all writes in primary).

> 2017-03-02T16:08:16.315+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1488470896:315136][17051:0x7ffdbd3d7dc0], file:mcse.45trace/collection-16-7756455024301269277.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: /app/data/mcse.45trace/collection-16-7756455024301269277.wt: handle-read: pread: failed to read 4096 bytes at offset 86474874880: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
>
> 2017-03-02T16:08:16.315+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure: ret resulted in status UnknownError: -31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_session_cache.cpp 95

Answer (score 0):

If you can solve that first problem with the replication lag, then you will probably get everything running OK. Take a look at the [Troubleshooting Replica Sets guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/troubleshoot-replica-sets/#check-the-replication-lag), it has some useful suggestions:

> Possible causes of replication lag include:
>
> **Network Latency**
>
> Check the network routes between the members of your set to ensure that there is no packet loss or network routing issue.
>   Use tools including `ping` to test latency between set members and `traceroute` to expose the routing of packets network endpoints.
>
> **Disk Throughput**
>
> If the file system and disk device on the secondary is unable to flush data to disk as quickly as the primary, then the secondary will have difficulty keeping state. Disk-related issues are incredibly prevalent on multi-tenant systems, including virtualized instances, and can be transient if the system accesses disk devices over an IP network (as is the case with Amazon’s EBS system.)
>   Use system-level tools to assess disk status, including `iostat` or `vmstat`.
>
> **Concurrency**
>
> In some cases, long-running operations on the primary can block replication on secondaries. For best results, configure [write concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/#wc-w) to require confirmation of replication to secondaries. This prevents write operations from returning if replication cannot keep up with the write load.
>   Use the [database profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-database-profiler) to see if there are slow queries or long-running operations that correspond to the incidences of lag.
>
> **Appropriate Write Concern**
>
> If you are performing a large data ingestion or bulk load operation that requires a large number of writes to the primary, particularly with `unacknowledged write concern`, the secondaries will not be able to read the oplog fast enough to keep up with changes.
>   To prevent this, request [write acknowledgement write concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/) after every 100, 1,000, or another interval to provide an opportunity for secondaries to catch up with the primary.
>   For more information see:
>   • [Write Concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/#wc-w)
>   • [Replica Set Write Concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/distributed-write-operations/#write-operations-replica-sets)
>   • [Oplog Size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/#replica-set-oplog-sizing)

Answer (score 0):

> WiredTiger error (-31802) file:xxx.wt

This could be related to corrupted `.wt` files (e.g. `WiredTiger.wt`/`WiredTiger.turtle`) as per [SERVER-31076](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31076) bug report.

Try running:

```
mongod --repair --dbpath /path/to/data/db
```

Also make sure all `data/db` files have the right read and write permission.